# How do I disable a button going blue when I hover over it IN XAML/VB?

Tags: vb.net, xaml, button, hover

I have created a login form in Visual Studio Blend. However the button I used will go blue when you hover over it. Is there anyway to stop this as it really bugs me. After searching about it some solutions came up however being new to this I don't really understand them. So I am looking for a basic and easy  solution.
My XAML code if it helps:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NEA"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Log In" Height="297" Width="345">
    <Grid Background="#FF403939" Height="267" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="337">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtUserName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26.774" Margin="8.778,48.444,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Username" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="317.529" BorderBrush="White" Background="#FF4D4B4B" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtPassword" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26.774" Margin="8.778,88.604,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="317.529" BorderBrush="White" Background="#FF4D4B4B" Foreground="White"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="chkRememberMe" Content="Remember Me" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19.778,137.399,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="White" Background="#FF726969"/>
        <Border x:Name="bor1" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Height="41" Margin="8.778,174.864,0,0"  CornerRadius="15" Background="#FF499E3C" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="317.529" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button x:Name="btnLogIn" Content="Log In" BorderBrush="#00707070" ClipToBounds="True" Background="#01F4F7FC" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="297.529" Height="41" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="9,-1,0,-1" >

            </Button> 
        </Border>

        <Button x:Name="btnForgot" Content="Forgotten Password" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24.601" Margin="186,132.079,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="124" Background="#00DDDDDD" Foreground="#FF00C5FF" BorderBrush="#00707070"/>
        <Label Content="Sign In" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35.444" Margin="8.778,8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77.222" Foreground="White" FontSize="18"/>
        <Label Content="Don't have an account?" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="63.35,233,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147.65" Foreground="#FFA09D9D"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnSignUp" Content="Sign Up" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="186,234.98,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75.572" Background="#00DDDDDD" BorderBrush="#00707070" Foreground="#FFC3C0C0" FontWeight="Bold"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is to edit the template for the button and modify the background color set in the trigger that uses the `IsMouseOver` property.  I believe you will find this trigger sets the background to "`#FFBEE6FD"` which is a light blue color.

To edit the button's template, in the Document Outline pane, right click on the button and select **Edit Template > Edit a Copy**.  This will insert the default `ControlTemplate` for a button.  Towards the bottom is the trigger associated with the `IsMouseOver` property.  Below this is the settter for the background where you can change the color if you prefer or, remove the setter and the background will no longer change.

If you right click per the above to edit the template, VS will automatically insert a `Template= "your template name"` line for the button.  You can use this same line for other buttons to achieve the same result.  Or, you can create a button style and provide a setter that assigns this template.  Then use this style for each button you want this same result.

Comment: Thanks for your help.